# populating TListView by using temp TListItems

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to refresh the list of listview in background, to do that i created a temporary TListItems, but i can not assign it to my listview. If i create TListItems and TListItem an access violation error occurs;

```
 var
  lis:TListItems;
  li:TListItem;
begin
  lis := TListItems.Create(nil);
  try
    li := TListItem.Create(nil);
    li.Caption := 'test'; // at this line av occurs
    lis.AddItem(li);
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListView1.Items.Assign(lis);
    finally
      ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    lis.Destroy();
  end;
```

If i use ListView1 as Owner while creating TListItems new line does not appear;

```
 var
  lis:TListItems;
  li:TListItem;
begin
  lis := TListItems.Create(ListView1);
  try
    li := TListItem.Create(lis);
    li.Caption := 'test';
    lis.AddItem(li);
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListView1.Items.Assign(lis);
    finally
      ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    lis.Destroy();
  end;
```

So i'want to prepare a new list in background and assign it to listview, how can i do it?

Note: preparing the list takes long time, this is why i'm preparing it in background. (i'm filling the list by a thread and protect it by using TRTLCriticalSection)

Comment: `TListView` wraps the list view of Windows. The items are managed via the Windows API. You cannot create an instance of `TListItems` the way you want to. You'll have to keep your own object list somewhere.

Comment: You can simply create a temporary TListView without placing it on the form, add items to it, then re-assign its items to your original TListView. Or, you can also try the excellent TVirtualTree which does not use a native Windows widget.

Comment: Use a virtual list view. You can do this with the native VCL control. When you say background do you mean a thread. You know about the vcl threading rules?

Comment: thank you all. i'll use a virtual list view as @DavidHeffernan recommend. And David, i've experienced before vcl threading, thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TListItems` and `TListItem` are very intimately tied to `TListView` and thus cannot be used in a standalone manner like you are attempting to do.  `TListItems` and `TListItem` both delegate to `TListView` to handle their work.

You get an AV in your first example because there is no `TListView` assigned to handle the work.

In your second example, the new list item does not appear correctly because it has not been added to the ListView yet when you assign its `Caption`, so there is nothing for the property setter to update.  And `AddItem()` doesn't apply pre-existing property values to a newly inserted list item.  The individual property setters must be used for that instead.

You must use the `TListItems.Add()` method FIRST instead of calling `AddItem()` directly, and THEN you can modify the new `TListItem` as needed, eg:

```
var
  NewList: TStringList;
  Lock: TCriticalSection;

...

// in a worker thread...

Lock.Enter;
try
  NewList.Clear;
  NewList.Add('test');
  ...
finally
  Lock.Leave;
end;
// signal main UI thread that a new list is ready ...

...

// in the main UI thread when the signal is received...

var
  li: TListItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Lock.Enter;
  try
    ListView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ListView1.Items.Clear;
      for i := 0 to NewList.Count-1 do
      begin
        li := ListView1.Items.Add;
        li.Caption := NewList[i];
        ...
      end;
    finally
      ListView1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    Lock.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

But, as David H said in comments, using the ListView in virtual mode (set the `OwnerData` property to `true` and use the `TListView.OnData...` events) is a better way to handle this situation:

```
var
  NewList: TStringList;
  Lock: TCriticalSection;

...

// in a worker thread...

Lock.Enter;
try
  NewList.Clear;
  NewList.Add('test');
  ...
finally
  Lock.Leave;
end;
// signal main UI thread that a new list is ready ...

...

// in the main UI thread...

private
  MyListItems: TStringList; // or whatever you want to use to store your item data

...

begin
  Lock.Enter;
  try
    MyListItems.Assign(NewList);
  finally
    Lock.Leave;
  end;
  ListView1.Items.Count := MyListItems.Count;
end;

procedure TMyForm.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := MyListItems[Item.Index];
  ...
end;
```

Comment: thank you Remy. i'll use a virtual list view and fill it by using 'Synchronize' in worker thread.